# Contenteditable not working properly for div tag inside a li tag

Tags: html, firefox, html-lists, contenteditable

I current have a need to have a contenteditable div tag inside an li tag.  See the following sample:

```
<li class="le-item" title="Area 7">
   <div class="le-item-menu"><span class='le-item-close'>remove</span></div>
   <div contentEditable="true" class="le-item-text">
       <p>Test</p>
   </div>
</li>
```

I'm using the li tag in an unordered list so that I can take advantage of the jQuery UI sortable option.  The issue I have is any contenteditable div tag within a li tag, acts differently.  Instead of new paragraphs, I'm getting new div tags.

I've racked my brain over this and am considering just writing my own sortable feature and reverting back to all div's.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Update: It appears this issue is specific to Firefox.

Comment: Do you have some jQuery code to go along with this?

Comment: There's no need.  I just tried isolating the jquery from the field and saw no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue is actually a problem with the version of Firefox.  There was a bug that created this problem that has been resolved. See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=460740.

Comment: This problem is not affecting Google chrome.